# Get Selected Radio button text with Capybara

Tags: xpath, radio-button, css-selectors, capybara

I have Radio buttons as below

```
<input id="Overriden" type="radio" value="false" name="Overriden" title="Current Setting" disabled="">Inherit
<input id="Overriden" type="radio" value="true" name="Overriden" checked="checked" title="Current Setting">Override
```

How do I get the text Overide or Inherit

I have tried

```
find("#Overriden[checked='checked']").text
find("#Overriden[checked='checked']").label
find("#Overriden[checked='checked']").innerHTML
find("#Overriden[checked='checked']").value ( which gives me true or false which I am not after)
```

XPATH solution welcome too.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

> find("#Overriden", :checked => 'checked').value

I used it like this in my app

> find("input[name=payment]", :checked => true).value

As my radio button group name is "payment" and I made attribute "checked" = true/false

So my answer will surely work for you if you didn't get any solution of this till now.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
find("[name='my_field_name'][checked]").value
```

Depending on your form, your field name may include angle brackets, which is fine:

```
find("[name='payment[payment_type]'][checked]").value
```

Just have a look at `<input name="my_field_name">` in your page source and use that name.

Answer (score 0):

I admit up front I do not know much about capybara, but I do know html. And the text you are trying to get resides outside an element (`input` elements do not have text directly associated with them). This residing outside an element tends to be difficult to get. That being so, I recommend putting the text following in either a `label` or a `span` tag. So something like this:

**Change HTML**

```
<input id="Overriden" type="radio" value="true" name="Overriden" checked="checked" title="Current Setting"><label>Override</label>
```

**Then Something Like This to Select**

(Here's where my lack of capybara's capabilities is shown: I don't know if it takes the css adjacent sibling selector `+` in its `find` string, but however you are able to select the adjacent sibling (next element) to your `input` in capybara.)

```
find("#Overriden[checked='checked'] + label").text
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I have managed to go after it with a hack. I couldn't change the HTML, as this is a short project and the app is from another team.

```
 settings=[] 
 pos=0
 i=0 
 all("div.inheritence").each do |elem|
   within(elem) do 
    all("#Overriden").each do |input_tag|
     i+=1 
     within(input_tag) do 
       if input_tag[:checked] 
           pos=i 
       end 
     end
    end 
   end 
   set=elem.text 
   settings =set.scan(/\w+/) 
  end 
settings[pos]
```